# OnClickListener doesn't work in a fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, onclicklistener

I have here a problem with the onClicklistener method in a fragment. If I click on the button nothing happens and I don't know why. No error and no output.
I've tried to implements the OnClickListener or set a `(Button)` before the `view.findViewById(R.id.button);` but nothing helps.
I've seen much questions here in Stack Overflow about this problem but no solution from there helps me :/

Do you have any ideas? Thank You!

```
package com.christoph.myapplication.ui.home;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.christoph.myapplication.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        final Button button= view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                System.out.println("Hallo");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this fragment is being called? OnClickListener is working fine

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Maybe do I have to write something special in my Main Activity? If I write `System.out.println("Hello")`;  after my view initialization the output comes if I start my app. But if I press that button nothing happens.

Comment: May be your calling activity have problem this looks fine I haved checked your code . Post your Activity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add click listener rather in onViewCreated function. Try it and let me know if it works. Check android fragment lifecycles documentation for more info.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean to implements the OnClickListener interface at OnCreateView method? I've tried that and makes no difference unfortunately.

Comment: No, in onViewCreated function. Then, please check if id of the view is correct. And yes, check if fragment is loaded. Can you paste your activity code, where fragment is loaded?

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip that my view-id is wrong! It was purple in my code so I haven't controlled that but actually the view hasn't an id. Now it works, thank you!

Comment: Yea, sometimes the most simple solution is the wright solution :)